# node - restart server after editing specific files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'd like to automatically restart the server after particular files are edited. 
Is there anything I can install to help me do that? - or will I need to watch the folder run a script accordingly.
Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) for that, there is even a [video tutorial on it](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/14-some-nodejs-tools.html#video).

Comment: Went with nodemon but I'm sure supervisor is fine too - thanks

Answer (score 7):

Use [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor). Install it with `npm install supervisor -g` and launch your code with `supervisor server.js` and you should be good to go. Note that by default it keeps an eye on the files that are in the same directory as the server.js and it's subdirectories, but it should be possible to add additional paths.

Comment: Dude, that's awesome.  You've made my life so much easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mdlawson/piping is good too.

> There are already node "wrappers" that handle watching for file
>   changes and restarting your application (such as node-supervisor), as
>   well as reloading on crash, but I wasn't fond of having that. Piping
>   adds "hot reloading" functionality to node, watching all your project
>   files and reloading when anything changes, without requiring a
>   "wrapper" binary.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon is good for it https://github.com/remy/nodemon
Also, if you want nodemon to restart your app only if particular files are changed, it is important to have `.nodemonignore` file in which you can tell changes to which files should be ignored by nodemon.

Example `.nodemonignore` file :

```sh
/public/*   # ignore all public resources

/.*         # any hidden (dot) files

*.md        # Markdown files

*.css       # CSS files

.build/*    # Build folder

/log/*
```